# Django admin AJAX подгрузка информации (Либо без оного)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ajax, django, django-admin

**Доброго времени суток!** 
Нуждаюсь в помощи сообщества. 

Итак, суть проблемы.

Есть модель:

```
    CHOICES = (
    (0,'New'),
    (1,'Reserved'),
    (2,'Block'),
    (3,'Sold'),
    (4,'Draft'),
)
coupon_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
coupon_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
town = models.ForeignKey(TownsAndDistricts, blank=True, null=False,
                                      on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
coupon_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
coupon_priority = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100, 'Enter digit from 0 to 100')])
coupon_status = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES, default=0)
coupon_user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
coupon_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Created')
```

Прошу обратить внимание на переменную `coupon_user`. В данном контексте имеет ключ к модели `User`, в которой есть переменная `shop_id`, которая соответственно имеет ключ к к магазину, в котором содержатся товары(product).

Проблема, которую никак не могу решить,ввиду несовершенства своих знаний сего прекрасного фреймворка:

В представлении админки при добавлении купонаБ при выборе поля `coupon_user` подгружать `coupon_product` который соответсвенно (в данном случае список товаров с магазина) привязан к определенному магазину, к которому привязан юзер.

Как же все же выводить список товаров, которые привязаны к магазину к которому привязан юзер.

Надеюсь на помощь, на вопросы в комментах отвечаю. Желательно показать подобную реализации или хорошенько дать пинка в нужном направлении.

 p.s. Гуглил. Подобных реализаций не отыскал.
**Хорошего дня!)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую дать пинка)

вот тут есть что-то похожее https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter

как бы сделал я. нужно перекрыть шаблон модели

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template

обрати внимание на

> And that’s it! If we placed this file in the templates/admin/my_app directory, our link would appear on the change form for all models within my_app.

Так, вот. Когда у тебя будет кастомная странница шаблона редактирования модели (основной код можно взять из site-packages), там нужно найти как рендерится select нужный тебе. На него нужно повесить событие on_change, при котором уже можно будет отправить запрос в бэкенд и получить список пользователей в зависимости от выбранной опции.

## Вариант 1

В админке уже присутствуют скрипты, которые трекают изменения в полях ChoiceField. Это нужно чтобы предоставить пользователю, не уходя со страницы, редактировать или создавать связанные модели.

Скрипт который нас инетерсует называется `RelatedObjectLookups.js`. Получить который можно запустив джангу и перейти по урл

`/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js`

Чтобы перекрыть этот скрипт необходимо создать путь `static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js` и положить туда полученный исходник. С этого момента ответственность за поддержку этого скрипта ложится на наши плечи!

[image: RelatedObjectLookups.js]

В скрипте есть метод `updateRelatedObjectLinks`. Переходим в конец и добавляем следующее

```
function updateRelatedObjectLinks(triggeringLink) {

...

// extend ajax request for products filtered by user_id
// получаем id элемента в котором сработало событие
        const elm_id = $this.attr("id");
        if (elm_id === "id_coupon_user") {
// мы ожидаем что id селекта будет именно id_coupon_user, это зависит от названия поля в модели Coupon
            const product = $(id_coupon_product);
// получаем ссылку на селект с продуктами, его id также зависит от имени поля
            product.val("");
// сразу можно очистить ранее выбранное
            $('#id_coupon_product option:gt(0)').remove();
// удаляем все опции из селекта продуктов, кроме первого, так как первая опция отвечает за None значение
            if (value) {
// если пользователь выбрал 0-ой элемент в селекте с юзерами то value будет пустым, тогда нам нечего делать.

// а теперь отправляем ajax запрос на бекенд указывая id выбранного пользователем юзера.
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/newapp/filter_products_by_user/" + value + "/",
                    success: function(newOptions){
// при успешном ответе мы ждем что нам вернется словарь {product_id: string represantation of product}
                        $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                            product.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));
                        });
                    }

                });
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
        // end
}
```

На этом с JS все. Теперь добавляем URL

Я добавил урл в корневой urls.py

```
from newapp import views as newapp_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('newapp/filter_products_by_user/<int:user_id>/', newapp_views.filter_products_by_user)
]
```

Добавляем вьюху.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

from . import models


def filter_products_by_user(request, user_id):
    products = models.Product.objects.filter(shop__customuser__id=user_id)
    return JsonResponse({x.id: str(x) for x in products})
```

И последних штрих, добавляем в настройки путь до статических файлов

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR.joinpath("static")
]
```

## Вариант 2

Находим шаблон change_form.html в файлах админки джанго

[image: change_form.html]

И копируем по пути `templates/admin/newapp/coupon/change_form.html`

- templates - директория для шаблонов по умолчанию
- admin - директория для шаблонов админки
- newapp - название приложения
- coupon - название модели

Добавляем скрипт, который будет отвечать за обновление селекта. Свой я назвал select_product.js

[image: select_product.js]

Пишем в нем следующее

```
/*global SelectBox, interpolate*/
// Handles related-objects functionality: lookup link for raw_id_fields
// and Add Another links.
'use strict';
{
    const $ = django.jQuery;

    function update_products(triggeringLink) {
        // extend ajax request for products filtered by user_id
        const $this = $(triggeringLink);
        const value = $this.val();
        const elm_id = $this.attr("id");
        if (elm_id === "id_coupon_user") {
            const product = $(id_coupon_product);
            product.val("");
            $('#id_coupon_product option:gt(0)').remove();
            if (value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/newapp/filter_products_by_user/" + value + "/",
                    success: function(newOptions){
                        $.each(newOptions, function(key, value) {
                            product.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", key).text(value));
                        });
                    }

                });
            } else {
                // do nothing
            }
        }
        // end
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(id_coupon_user).change(function(e) {
            const event = $.Event('django:update-related');
            $(this).trigger(event);
            if (!event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                update_products(this);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Это тот самый кусок который добавлялся в RelatedObjectLookups.js.

А в шаблон добавляем следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и конечно же нам также нужна view из первого примера, url и настройка STATICFILES_DIRS

Мой models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models


class TownsAndDistricts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Product(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Coupon(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        (0, 'New'),
        (1, 'Reserved'),
        (2, 'Block'),
        (3, 'Sold'),
        (4, 'Draft'),
    )

    coupon_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    coupon_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    town = models.ForeignKey(TownsAndDistricts, blank=True, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    coupon_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    coupon_priority = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100, 'Enter digit from 0 to 100')])
    coupon_status = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES, default=0)
    coupon_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # свойство auto_now_add автоматически укажет текущую дату при создании записи.
    coupon_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
```

После этого придется держать в уме, что если у модели Coupon поменяется любое из полей coupon_product, coupon_user, то эти изменения должны быть отражены в скрипте. Иначе перестанет работать.

В скрипте нет инициализации, т.е. при загрузке страницы на данный момент отображаются все продукты. Уж с этим точно справишься.

Еще я бы порекомендовал каким либо образом (csrf например и авторизация) защитить урл `/newapp/filter_products_by_user/`, так как на данный момент любой пользователь может отправить туда запрос и получить информацию по продуктам. Хотя... может и не нужно. Я лишь хочу обратить на это внимание.

Comment: Пинок принят, но пока не могу скурить. Можно более детально?)

Comment: достаточно детально?)

Comment: Максимально детально! Огромнейшая благодарность!